# is it possible to use VBA code to sort a range within a range?

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I know how to sort a range by value. I have this code

```
Sub calander4()
Range("currentmonth").Sort _
Key1:=Range("currentmonthrating"), Order1:=xlDescending
End Sub
```

this code sorts range within columns highest to lowest by value. what i want on top of that is to sort the columns them selves left to right by a value. say the second top cell. which i would of course name and make range. is it possible?

Comment: To be clear: you want to change the order of the columns, e.g. column A can become column D?

Comment: You would have to order and transpose, probably.

Comment: Excel supports sorting left to right in addition to the “regular” direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the *Orientation* parameter.

```
Option Explicit

Sub calander5()
    With Range("currentmonth")
        .Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, 1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
              Orientation:=xlSortColumns, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```

See [Range.Sort Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-sort-method-excel) for more.